# Calling Controller Method in link_to from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My application has deals which have orders. In my admin area I want to be able to process the orders manually.

In my access/deals view

```
<%= link_to "Process Orders", "Not sure what I put here?" %>
```

in my access/deals_controller

```
def process_orders
   @deals = Deal.find(params[:id]
   @orders = @deals.orders.where("state" == ?, "pending")

   @orders.each do |order|
     #order processing code here
   end
end
```

How should I structure my link_to method to call the process_orders method in my admin/deals controller?

I thought something like

```
<%= link_to "Process Orders", access_deal_path(deal) %>
```

which give me the following url

```
 localhost:3000/access/deals/9
```

how do I get something like

```
localhost:3000/access/deals/9/process_orders
```

I'm also open to suggestions on moving the processing_orders method to model or helper if that is a better way of doing this.

My excerpt of my routes file.

```
  resources :deals do
    resources :orders
  end

  namespace "access" do
    resources :deals, :podcasts, :pages, :messages
  end
```

Comment: would it be access_deals_process_orders_path?

Comment: it ended up being process_orders_access_deal_path(deal) but I had to add a new route thanks to @Kevin-Tsoi

Comment: I was on the right track! Just completely backwards and wrong :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do 1 of the following:

Create a custom route:

```
match 'access/deals/:id/process_orders' => 'access/deals#process_orders', :as => 'access_deal'
```

then you can use this link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Process Orders", access_deal_path(deal) %>
```

OR

Add a member route:

```
namespace "access" do
    resources :deals do
        member do
            get :process_orders
        end
    end
end
```

Your link_to will look something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Process Orders", process_orders_access_deal_path(deal) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a specific _path that be great, but I know I've been in situations where I wanted more explicit control.

The Ruby API here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Gives this example:

```
link_to "Profile", :controller => "profiles", :action => "show", :id => @profile
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nicer if you move the `process_orders` method to your `OrdersController` but this is your decision.

To get your code working just add this route to your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :deals do
  get :process_orders
  resources :orders
end
```

and call it with `<%= link_to("Process Orders", deal_process_orders(deal)) %>`.