# Rails 3 how do I use link_to to change the value of a boolean in the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, routes, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a simple link that will allow an admin to approve a user on my website

quite similar to what this guy was trying : [In Rails 3 how do I use button_to to change the value of a boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124781/in-rails-3-how-do-i-use-button-to-to-change-the-value-of-a-boolean)

Here's how it was supposed to work :

1. Admin clicks the link to approve a user
2. The link calls the activate function in UsersController
3. The active function calls that users model
4. the user model updates the approved attribute to true and saves it

and here's how I was going to do it

in my users#index view

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %> 
 <%= link_to 'Approve', :action => "index", :method => 'activate', :id => user.id, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %> 
<% end %>
```

in my userController

```
def activate
  @user = User.find(params[:user])
  @user.activate_user
end
```

in my user model

```
def activate_user 
  self.approved = 'true'
  self.save
end
```

and my routes

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

resources :users do
  member do
    get 'activate'
    put 'activate'
  end
end

match "users/:id/activate" => "users#activate"
```

Now when I click the link (to approve users), I'm sent back to the user index page (like I'm supposed to) but the user field "approved" is still set to false :I

The URL I get after clicking the link :

```
  http://localhost:3000/users?class=btn+btn-mini+btn-danger&id=2&method=activate
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

As suggested iv added the URL to the link_to helper

```
<% @users.each do |user| %> 
  <%= link_to "Approve", :controller => "users", :id => user.id, :action => "activate", :method => :put, :approved => true %> 
<% end %>
```

When I click the helper link I get

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

in app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `activate'

```
def activate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attribute(params[:user])
  redirect_to "/users?approved=false"
end
```

line 7 where the error is 
    @user.update_attribute(params[:user])

What else should I put there?

oh and here is my route for this method

```
match "/users/:id/activate" => "users#activate"
```

**UPDATE V2**
So I have changed that update line to :

```
@user.update_attributes(@user.approved, "true")
```

and it seems to do everything i want it to do except changing the value to true !

I've also tried to use 1 for true (and the update_attribute function) and non-strings.. running out of ideas here lol

**The solution**

Well this is awkward but so it happens that in my user model i had `attr_accessor :approved`  this resulted in that the model never went to the database to update the `:approved` column BUT instead it updated the local variable `:approved` so next time when I looked at the column then of course the `:approved` value had not changed

tldr? 
if you have attr_accessor in your model with the same name as the column your trying to update => remove it

Comment: The second parameter of link_to should be a url, then you put in your options. Try `link_to "Approve", users_path, #...`

Comment: Tru running rake routes and see which route actually points to `users#activate`. Use the helper variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can update the code below

You View

```
<% @users.each do |user| %> 
<%= link_to 'Approve', active_user_path(user) %> 
<% end %>
```

You Controller

```
def activate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attribute(:approved, true)
    redirect_to "something"
  else
   render "something"
  end 
end
```

Your routes

```
match "users/:id/activate" => "users#activate", :as => "active_user"
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: i made the changes you suggested but i still get this error  `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`  for this line   `@user.update_attribute(approved: true)`

Comment: Okey this is super wierd : it works to change the `:email` but not `:approved` attribute, does it matter that im using sqlite ? it seems to prefer to have 't' instead of true (but the value still dosnt change in the db)

Comment: Seems like Rails and Sqlite dont communicate very well when it comes to boolians ! i need some kind of an adapter, but you have solved my old problem thanks ! :)

Comment: @Matti the `update_attribute` method takes two arguments, not one. You are passing a hash, which is a single argument. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8813988/904042) for a more detailed explanation of this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you aren't calling link_to properly. Notice that you have the action as a http parameter and not part of the URL.

The URL should be

`http://localhost:3000/users/123/activate`

Look at the examples on this page:

`http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to`

I think you need to use the :controller => 'users', :action => 'activate'.

Remember you can use a string here for the path as well: `"/users/${@user.id}/activate"`

Comment: Nice thanks for the link ! After reading the API im not sure if link_to is the right method to do this. All i want is a button that calls the "activate" function in the usercontroller that makes the approved attribute true then just return to the users index, should i use link_to for that ?

Comment: Maybe the button tag would be better. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254720/is-there-a-way-with-rails-form-helper-to-produce-a-button-tag-for-submit

Comment: I think i can get link_to to work, you where right about the missing url, but it has lead me to a new error please see my updated post :)

Answer (score 0):

The `attr_accessor` method will create an instance variable as well as the getter and setter for said variable.

When you try to update the database column with that name, it uses the instance variable instead. This is useful if you want to have a "virtual column", that will act as an actual column but is stored in memory.

For database columns you have `attr_accessible` which allows for mass assignment of that column (this will be deprecated in rails 4), or you can use no method to define the accessibility of columns and let `ActiveRecord` deal with it.